# Polymer google-client-loader, does not care about root property

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, polymer-1.0, google-client

I'm trying to get my `Polymer1.0` app to work with my google cloud endpoints API but for some reason it seems that `google-client-loader` doesn't care what i put in for `root`, it always goes to `content.googleapis.com` to fetch the API , of course it isn't there !

code:

```
<google-client-loader
                id="api" name="parliament" version="v1"
                root="http://localhost:8080/_ah/api"></google-client-loader>
```

getting:

```
GET https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/parliament/v1/rest?fields=rootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods&pp=0 404 (OK)
```

tried:

- api-root
- apiRoot
- root
- api-root with app-id
- apiRoot with app-id
- root with app-id

doesn't work !

What's the problem ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct attribute to use is `api-root` (which works, just tested).

```
<google-client-loader
     id="api" name="parliament" version="v1"
     api-root="http://localhost:8080/_ah/api"></google-client-loader>
```

You have to make sure to use the latest version of the `google-apis` element collection, i.e. with this dependency in your `bower.json`:

```
"google-apis": "GoogleWebComponents/google-apis#^1.0.1"
```